# Access NULL data on TLS object on Windows

Tags: c++, macros

I encountered a weird thing out of my understanding about TLS object access on windows. I set a global object into TLS, and access its data "test_sym" from somewhere say test.cpp like the code below. It works on Mac, but on windows test_sym returns NULL. But if I explicitly defined test_sym in test.cpp (static Persistent test_sym), then it works on windows...

in var.h

```
#define VAR(x) (globals_get()->x)

struct globals {
v8::Persistent<v8::String> test_sym;
...
};

globals* globals_get();
```

in var.cpp

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
static unsigned long loop_key;
#else
static pthread_key_t loop_key;
#endif
static uv_once_t tls_once_guard = UV_ONCE_INIT;

static void init_tls() {
#if defined(_WIN32)
  loop_key = TlsAlloc();
#else
  pthread_key_create(&loop_key, NULL);
#endif
}

globals* globals_get() {
  uv_once(&tls_once_guard, init_tls);

#if defined(_WIN32)
  void* data = TlsGetValue(loop_key);
#else
  void* data = pthread_getspecific(loop_key);
#endif
  if (data == NULL) {
    data = new globals();
#if defined(_WIN32)
    TlsSetValue(loop_key, data);
#else
    pthread_setspecific(loop_key, data);
#endif
  }

  return static_cast<globals*>(data);
}
```

Two ways to define test_sym in test.cpp, a does not work, but b works well.

Way a:

```
 #include "vars.h"
 #define test_sym VAR(test_sym)
 ...
 void test()
 {
     HandleScope scope;
     object_->Set(test_sym, Integer::New(stream_->write_queue_size));// test_sym is NULL on windows!!!
 }
```

Way b:

```
static Persistent<String> test_sym;
...
void test()
{
    HandleScope scope;
    object_->Set(test_sym, Integer::New(stream_->write_queue_size));// test_sym is OK.
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't really see how it's useful to compare the Windows and Mac behavior of this code since they're not really similar at all. If your Windows code doesn't work, then investigate it as *Windows* code and ignore the Mac code. What value do you expect to get instead of null? Is null even a valid value for a `Persistent<String>`?

Comment: Thanks Rob. I agree that it's not useful to compare code on Win and Mac. I should compare two ways below
a: define test_sym in struct globals
b: define test_sym in test.cpp as a static global
b works well, but a does not work...
NULL is not a valid value for Persistent<String> so it cause crash directly. I don't know why...